# root directory - www or public_html

Tags: webserver, root

Is the root directory where all files are kept (directly from accessing from FTP) always "www" or "public_html" depending on what OS? Or is it possible to rename this folder? And if so, what would be unique about this folder to be able to identify it? i.e. currently I just wrote this;

```
my $root;
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($DB_ftpserver, Debug => 0) 
                              or die "Cannot connect to some.host.name: $@";
$ftp->login($DB_ftpuser, $DB_ftppass) or die "Cannot login ", $ftp->message;
my @list = $ftp->dir;

if( scalar @list != 0 ) {
  foreach( @list ){
     if( $_ =~ m/www$/g ){
       $root = "www";
       last;
     }elsif( $_ =~ m/public_html$/g ){
       $root = "public_html";
       last;
     }
   }
 }
```

but would not work if it has a different name.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: My Document Root is always ~/domainname/ for each website. You can configure this how you like.

Answer (score 2):

I'll speak in terms of Apache httpd, since it's a very popular webserver.

The root directory where all files are kept, is generically named **DocumentRoot**.
Please bear in mind that files are kept in **DocumentRoot** for **being served** by the web server, not for being shown to you when you log in via FTP. FTP is a totally different protocol that is not related to web sites and in this context it is just a way to allow you, the user, modify/update files on a remote server.

The **www** / **public_html** directory that you talk about in your question is probably not **DocumentRoot**. This is additional functionality of Apache, the **mod_userdir** module. Please consult [its documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_userdir.html).

As said in the docs, there's an **UserDir** setting in Apache's configuration file which lets you customize the name of these user directories, from where the web server will serve the sites that belong to different users.

Since there's no restriction on **UserDir**, you can have anything there, even **foobar**. You can judge by the content of this directory (HTML files, images) that this can be an user directory that holds a site that's being exposed by Apache. But I'd say that doing this automatically with a script seems unreliable to me. Not to mention that for example you can have a **public_html** directory that is not an user directory, its name matching the default value for Apache **UserDir** setting being just a simple coincidence. Ideally, in order to judge about a directory if it's an **UserDir**, you'll need access to the configuration file of the web server. And normally you don't have it. Web hosting providers can put at most user-specific logs in your home directory.

To summarize: if you need to perform any actions with the user directory, have it come to your script as input data: command-line argument, setting from a config file etc, but do not try to guess it.

Answer (score 0):

The name is configurable in Apache ([DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot) - default, according to the 2.2.x documentation, is /usr/local/apache/htdocs).  My machine at the office uses neither of the options you mention (offhand, I think it uses htdocs, but its a while since I last fiddled with it).

OTOH, since you mention FTP, perhaps you are thinking of something else; the base directory is still configurable, though.